# PackageKit database disk image malformed

Tags: apt

Every time I use apt, I get the "timeout reached error".  Looking at `/var/log/syslog`, I see:

```
dbus[619]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service'
systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
PackageKit: daemon start
PackageKit: daemon quit
packagekitd[12925]: Failed to load the backend: Failed to execute statement 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF': database disk image is malformed
systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
gnome-software[2433]: running search with refine-flags=require-icon with timeout=60 with max-results=20 with search=packagek on plugin=snap took 378ms
gnome-software[2433]: running search with refine-flags=require-icon with timeout=60 with max-results=20 with search=packageki on plugin=snap took 432ms
gnome-software[2433]: running search with refine-flags=require-icon with timeout=60 with max-results=20 with search=packagekit on plugin=snap took 231ms
gnome-software[2433]: failed to call gs_plugin_refine on packagekit-refine: failed to resolve package_ids: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PackageKit: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out
```

Anyone run into this issue before?  Is there any way to repair the database?  Or could I just re-install packagekit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *did* work:

```
sudo apt-get remove packagekit
sudo apt-get purge packagekit
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

Alternately you should be able to use the following instead:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge packagekit
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

I had hoped to find a better solution.  I did find there's the `pkcon` command with the `repair` option, but the relies on `packagekitd` to be running to interact with the database.

I couldn't find any references online as to where the database was stored, or how to otherwise deal with the issue.  Most of the issues relating to PackageKit are regarding Fedora, RedHat or CentOS, so not as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The database file is the following.  Delete it and restart the packagekit service

/var/lib/PackageKit/transactions.db